# Qt network access manager widget application crash

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkrequest

I'm making a gui application where I'm sending data to my web service and receiving a JSON response. Using the debugger I found out that I manage to send data and receive a response from my server. However, the app crashes before the value changes in the plaintext. I succeeded once i changed the number of arrays in **AESEnkriptiraj** to two, but even then, spamming the button would crash the application. The problem might be in my thread management, but i don't know what it is.

decryptionwindow.h

```
#ifndef DECRYPTIONWINDOW_H
#define DECRYPTIONWINDOW_H

#include <QWidget>
#include "QFile.h"
#include "qfiledialog.h"
#include "qtextstream.h"
#include "kriptiraj.h"


namespace Ui {
class DecryptionWindow;
}

class DecryptionWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT


public:
    explicit DecryptionWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~DecryptionWindow();

signals:

public slots:
    void AESkriptiranoVrati(QString Poruka);

private:

private slots:
    void on_btnFilePath_clicked();

    void on_btnKriptirajAES_clicked();

    void on_btnDekriptirajAES_clicked();

private:
    Ui::DecryptionWindow *ui;
};

#endif // DECRYPTIONWINDOW_H
```

decryptionWindow.cpp

```
    #include "decryptionwindow.h"
#include "ui_decryptionwindow.h"
#include <QTextCodec>



Kriptiraj *kriptiraj= new Kriptiraj();


DecryptionWindow::DecryptionWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::DecryptionWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(kriptiraj, SIGNAL(Poruka(QString)), this, SLOT(AESkriptiranoVrati(QString)));

}

void DecryptionWindow::on_btnKriptirajAES_clicked()
{

    kriptiraj->AESEnkriptiraj(ui->txtSadrzajDatotekeAES->toPlainText(), ui->txtKljucAES->toPlainText(), "AES", "Kriptiraj");

}

void DecryptionWindow::AESkriptiranoVrati(QString poruka){
    ui->txtSadrzajDatotekeAES->setPlainText(poruka);

}
```

kriptiraj.h

```
    #ifndef KRIPTIRAJ_H
#define KRIPTIRAJ_H

#include <qobject.h>
#include <qnetworkaccessmanager.h>
#include <qthread.h>
#include <QtScript/qscriptengine>
#include <QtScript/QScriptValueIterator>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QJsonArray>
#include <QEventLoop>
#include <QDebug>

class Kriptiraj : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:

    explicit Kriptiraj();
    ~Kriptiraj();



signals:
    Nastavi();
    Poruka(QString);


public slots:


    void AESEnkriptiraj(QString tekst, QString kljuc, QString metoda, QString zahtjev);

    QString IzvuciPodatak(QNetworkReply* reply);


private:

    QNetworkAccessManager *networkManager;
private slots:



};



#endif // KRIPTIRAJ_H
```

kriptiraj.cpp

```
    #include "kriptiraj.h"

Kriptiraj::Kriptiraj()
{
    networkManager= new QNetworkAccessManager();
    connect(networkManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(IzvuciPodatak(QNetworkReply*)));

}

void Kriptiraj::AESEnkriptiraj(QString tekst, QString kljuc, QString metoda, QString zahtjev){


    QNetworkReply* Reply;
    QString url ="http://jospudjaatfoi.000webhostapp.com/OS2/AESenkripcija.php?tekst="+tekst+"&kljuc="+kljuc+"&metoda="+metoda+"&zahtjev="+zahtjev;
    QUrl Url(url);
    QNetworkRequest Request;
    Request.setUrl(Url);
    Reply = networkManager->get(Request);

}

QString Kriptiraj::IzvuciPodatak(QNetworkReply* reply){


    QString data = (QString) reply->readAll();
    //reply->deleteLater();
    QJsonDocument JSON= QJsonDocument::fromJson(data.toUtf8());
    QJsonObject JSONObject = JSON.object();
    QJsonValue JSONValue = JSONObject.value("result");


    QString link =JSONValue.toString();
    emit Poruka(link);


}



Kriptiraj::~Kriptiraj()
{


}
```

Basically I have two connects, one in initialization of decryptionwindow and the other in initialization of kriptiraj. The code goes on when i run **on_btnKriptirajAES_clicked()** which runs **AESEnkriptiraj** which sends of a get request which, when finished using connection runs **IzvuciPodatak** which emits **Poruka** back to decryptionwindow.cpp connection which runs **AESkriptiranoVrati**. After that it crashes.

Sorry for bad naming and other practices, and sorry for using native language in my code, combined with English.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: Is the url real or have you invented it for the example?

Comment: Did you try to print and validate the response body after `readAll()` and before updating the text box?

Comment: Why are you converting data from `readAll()` to `QString` and then passing it to [`QJsonDocument::fromJson()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.html#fromJson) using `toUtf8()`? Because, [`readAll()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readAll) returns you a `QByteArray` and [`QString::toUtf8()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toUtf8)also does the same then why there is `QString` there. I don't see the point.

Comment: Another thing is that you don't need that `Reply`. Take a look at this [example](http://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_Downloading_Files_QNetworkAccessManager_QNetworkRequest.php).

Comment: Yes, I used a debugger, after I get JSON i used a breakpoint, and after i continue that, i get a segmentation fault
Here is the result of the JSON:
http://prntscr.com/i335z0
Those are the result i want

Comment: Also, you're right, i've removed Reply and removed the QString bit

Comment: Also the value does arrive to the AESkriptiranoVrati
 **http://prntscr.com/i33ci2**
the breakpoint is at the end of that function